# Conflicting roles and privileges in MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb, access-control

I have database `traffic` and in that two collections `readMe` and `readWriteMe`.
I want to create a user in `mongoDB` that can do the following -

1. read the `readMe` collection.
2. read and write to the `readWriteMe` collection.
3. can create new collection and have `readWrite` authorization to that collection.

I have role say `myRole` - I tried giving following privileges to this role

```
privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "traffic", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find", "insert", "remove" ] },
       { resource: { db: "traffic", collection: "readMe"}, actions: ["find"]},
      ]
```

but it allows to insert in `readMe` collection too!

This raises the question - what happens in the case of conflicting privileges. Which is given more priority etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are not specifying the collection name on the first permission. Try:

```
 privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "traffic", collection: "readWriteMe" }, actions: [ "find", "insert", "remove" ] },
       { resource: { db: "traffic", collection: "readMe"}, actions: ["find"]}
      ]
```

If you want the same user to create collections and be able to readWrite them, I think it's impossible to not grant enough privileges without him being able to somehow read and write your `readMe` collection. You could try applying the [createCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/privilege-actions/#authr.createCollection) along with [grantRole](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/privilege-actions/#authr.grantRole) but this would allow the user to self assign the readWrite role to itself for the readMe collection too

Comment: The above set of privileges will give me `rw` right for `readWriteMe` and `r` for `readMe` but it won't allow me to create new collections.

Comment: Oh sorry, I hadn't seen this requisite. I'll update my answer

Comment: Yeah I tried giving `createCollection` and it indeed gave `rw` request to `readMe` too!